# image_path() generates wrong image path for engine assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

I'm using rails4 + ruby2 and trying to create a rails engine. This engine has a separated assets dir with it's own stylesheets (sass), javascripts and images.

The thing is, `image_path()` sass helper generates a wrong image path. Let's say my engine is called 'Admin'. There is a image file called `arrow.png` in `/admin/app/assets/images/admin/arrow.png`.

If, in `application.css.sass` i'm gonna use `background: url(image_path('arrow.png'))`, it will generate a following url: `/assets/arrow.png` which will not work. The proper url is `/assets/admin/arrow.png`.

There are probably two possible solutions right now:

1. Move all `/admin/app/assets/admin/images/*` to `/admin/app/assets/images`, or
2. prefix all image names in `image_path()` method with engine name which gives me `image_path('admin/arrow.png')`.

Are there any other, better, ways to handle this thing?

Answer (score 2):

**The best solution is:**

`image_path('admin/arrow.png')` OR `asset_path('admin/arrow.png')`

As Subfolders are also merged into `public/assets`. That means both `app/assets/javascripts/subfolder/*` and `app/assets/stylesheets/subfolder/*` now live in `public/assets/subfolder/*`